# tab of object undefined in Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently facing a problem :

After fetching an API response request I wanted to store those informations in tab.

I decided to create an object to get an object tab and after do whatever I want with.

The problem is that when I display the tab I can see what is inside, but when i want to get tab[0] for example, it displays me 'undefined'. I'm quite blocked at this point since i don't really know why my tab[O] is undefined...

Here's the code i use :

```
let tab = [];

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/assets").then(response => {
    response.json().then(data => {
        for(let i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
            let obj = {
                logo: data[i]["symbol"],
                name: data[i]["name"],
                price: data[i]["price"]
            }
            tab.push(obj);
        }
    });
}).catch(
    err => {
        console.log("err: " + err)
    })

console.log(tab)
console.log(tab.length)
console.log(tab[0])
```

[Console display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6a2b.png)

general.js:218 = console.log(tab)

general.js:219 = console.log(tab.length)

general.js:220 = console.log(tab[0])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Your code goes 1) Declare `tab` 2) Send an asynchronous request that might be resolved at some point in the future. 3) _Immediately_ log the value of `tab` (still undefined) when the promise of data hasn't been resolved. You may find [this answer informative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). [Maybe also this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: NOT part of the question but `if (!response.ok) { throw new Error('Network response was not OK'); }`  may prove to have value here

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your `tab` object to the console before the request has had time to finish. Try moving the `console.log()` statements into your request script after it has received the data:

```
let tab = [];

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/assets").then(response => {
    response.json().then(data => {
        for(let i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
            let obj = {
                logo: data[i]["symbol"],
                name: data[i]["name"],
                price: data[i]["price"]
            }
            tab.push(obj);
        }
        console.log(tab)
        console.log(tab.length)
        console.log(tab[0])
    });
}).catch(
    err => {
        console.log("err: " + err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking it before the `fetch` returns, you need to do it after like such:

```js
let tab = [];

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/assets")
  .then(response => {
    response.json().then(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let obj = {
          logo: data[i]["symbol"],
          name: data[i]["name"],
          price: data[i]["price"]
        };
        tab.push(obj);
      }
    })
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(tab);
    console.log(tab.length);
    console.log(tab[0]);
  })
  .catch(
    err => {
      console.log("err: " + err);
    });
```